# Result array not being mutated using Swift Accelerate

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework

I'm going through the examples in Apple's documentation at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/controlling_vdsp_operations_with_stride) site, and I can't get the following code to work in a Playground:

```swift
let stride = vDSP_Stride(1)

let a: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let b: [Float] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

let n = vDSP_Length(a.count)

var c = [Float](repeating: 0,
                count: a.count)

vDSP_vadd(a, stride,
          b, stride,
          &c, stride,
          n)

print(c)
```

It should print `[11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 55.0]`, but instead it just prints `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`, like the inout result array `c` isn't getting mutated at all.

Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: I think your problem is that your are using the same "stride" for the 3 variables... There should be one independent stride for each of them...

Comment: Not reproducible for me. It prints `[11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 55.0]`

Comment: This works fine for me too. Incidentally, did you know there's a Swift friendly API:

`let a: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  let b: [Float] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]; let c = vDSP.add(a, b)
`